# Uniqueness of positive solutions to the n-vortex type equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde

The $n$-vortex equation, in the context of optical vortex solitons, is of the form 
\begin{equation}
-(ru_{r})_r+\dfrac{n^2}{r}u+\beta ru= f(u^2)ru,\quad r\in (0,\infty),\\
u(0)=0=u(\infty),
\end{equation}
where $n$ is a nonzero integer, $\beta$ an undetermined parameter, and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can be taken to be a polynomial for simplicity. Are there any uniqueness results for positive solutions of such an equation when $n\neq 0$ on an unbounded domain as given or even on a finite domain $[0,R]$ with $u(0)=0=u(R)$ and $R>0$ sufficiently large? Any comments/references would be highly appreciated.